# Wake on lan with only two devices on the network

Tags: network-interface, ethernet, wake-on-lan

I am trying to make wake-on-lan work with one device I am connected to directly. I have enabled the feature in the BIOS, and tried multiple times to use `wakeonlan` with it.

Because there are only two devices on the ethernet network, and the second is shut down, I suspect my computer to not try to send the packet on the wire.
At first, I saw that my network interface was down, so I brought it up with `ip link set dev enp0s25 up`. However it did not helped.

I checked with wireshark, and no packets were sent on the interface. Wireshark also does not see when I try to ping or ARPing through the ethernet. However Wireshark works perfectly with a turned-on computer on the other side of the cable.

So, how can I be sure that my comptuter tries to send the WoL packet through the wire, and if not, how can I make it work?

Some additional information on sender device :

- Ubuntu 16.04
- Output of ip addr. Note the lack of `LOWER_UP` and the `state DOWN`:

```
2: enp0s25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 14:58:d0:b7:45:33 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.170.70/16 scope global enp0s25
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

- Output of ethtool:

```
Settings for enp0s25:
    Supported ports: [ TP ]
    Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Supported pause frame use: No
    Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
    Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full 
                            100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full 
                            1000baseT/Full 
    Advertised pause frame use: No
    Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
    Speed: Unknown!
    Duplex: Unknown! (255)
    Port: Twisted Pair
    PHYAD: 2
    Transceiver: internal
    Auto-negotiation: on
    MDI-X: Unknown (auto)
    Supports Wake-on: pumbg
    Wake-on: g
    Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                   drv probe link
    Link detected: no
```

- I tried the command `wakeonlan 44:8a:5b:3d:7e:8a`, and also with the `-i 192.168.170.06`

**Edit**

Additional information on the second host:

- OS is Debian 5
- ifconfig output:

```
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:8a:5b:3d:7e:8a
          inet addr:192.168.170.06  Bcast:192.168.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:296 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:190 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:71526 (69.8 KiB)  TX bytes:42828 (41.8 KiB)
          Memory:febe0000-fec00000
```

- `ethtool eth1` output:

```
Settings for eth1:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        Supports Wake-on: pumbag
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000001 (1)
        Link detected: yes
```

Comment: Please include the network config of the second machine

Comment: Also, if you use `-i`, you have to specify the broadcast address (i.e. 192.178.170.255 for a /24 subnet).

Comment: Can you try with a switch between the two devices, so we could confirm your suspect ?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have a switch :/